# How to Pass parameter to SQlDataSource from gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

Gridview has many columns and a Delete button as well. Delete button is a control as TemplateField

```
<asp:TemplateField>
 <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" CommandName="Delete" Text='<%#     Eval("disabled").ToString()=="False" ? "Disabled" : "Enabled" %>'
 OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to take this action?');"
 runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Now associated SQLDataSource's Delete command's stored procedure is expecting two parameters. One is going from DataKeyNames (RowID), other one i wanna pass is the Text of btnDelete (True or False).

How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend doing it in the code behind. On btnDelete click i would iterate through every row in your gridview and check all the datakeynames. Once i found the one you want to delete you will need to send that back to you db. You can use either an orm like linq, ado.net, or a straight sqlcmd.

Answer (score 0):

Please See this Code. I implement and works fine

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Add" HeaderStyle-CssClass="grid_Title">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("TrackID")%>' />
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_Projects" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SentricMusicFunctionalityConnectionString2 %>"
                           SelectCommand="select* from MassTraxCatProjects where Fk_AgencyId=@CatalogAgencyId and fk_trackid=@TrackID) ">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:SessionParameter DbType="Int32" DefaultValue="CatalogAgencyId" Name="CatalogAgencyId"
                                      SessionField="CatalogAgencyId" />
                <asp:ControlParameter DefaultValue="TrackID" Name="TrackID" ControlID="**HiddenField1**" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_ProjectType" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_Projects"
                          Width="100px" DataTextField="ProjectName" DataValueField="ProjectId">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```